# Long time of uploading video to vimeo in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, video, upload, vimeo

Uploading video from my app where I'm using 'tus' approach take 5 minut to upload movie. Uploading same movie on same phone but via vimeo web manager took 2 minut with conversion. Can you provide me some tips what can I do wrong or maybe there is some other explanation?
There is my uploading method:

```
Future<String?> uploadVideo(
    File file,
    String courseID,
    dynamic uploadProgressCallback(int prog),
  ) async {
    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(
        baseUrl,
        data: {
          "upload": {
            "approach": "tus",
            "size": "${file.lengthSync()}",
          },
          "name": "$courseID",
          "privacy": {
            "embed": "private",
            "view": "nobody",
          },
        },
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            "Authorization": bearer,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4"
          },
        ),
      );
      final Map parsed = json.decode(response.data);
      print(parsed);
      print("parsed ${parsed["upload"]["upload_link"]}");
      String id = parsed["uri"];

      id = id.substring(8, id.length);
      print(id);
      print(file);

     await Dio().patch(
        parsed["upload"]["upload_link"],
        data: Stream.fromIterable(file.readAsBytesSync().map((e) => [e])),
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            "Content-Length": "${file.lengthSync()}",
            "Tus-Resumable": "1.0.0",
            "Upload-Offset": "0",
            "Content-Type": "application/offset+octet-stream",
            "Accept": "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4",
          },
        ),
        onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
          final progress = ((sent / total) * 100).floor();

          uploadProgressCallback(progress);
        },
      );
      return id;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73413428/getting-duration-0-form-uploaded-vimeo-video-response can you please answer it..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73414629/vimeo-upload-video-api-resource-created-but-vimeo-video-duration-is-0
can you please answer it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('your_url'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'bearer $accessToken',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      
      body: jsonEncode({
        "upload": {
          "approach": "tus",
          "size": file.lengthSync(),
        },
      }),
    );
    final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
   // final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.data);
    String uploadLink = responseJson['upload']['upload_link'];

    // 2. Upload the video file
    final tusResponse = await http.patch(
      Uri.parse(uploadLink),
      headers: {
        'Tus-Resumable': '1.0.0',
        'Upload-Offset': '0',
        'Content-Type': 'application/offset+octet-stream',
      },
      body: file.readAsBytesSync(),
    );

    // 3. Check the upload status
    final statusResponse = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(uploadLink),
      headers: {
        'Tus-Resumable': '1.0.0',
      },
    );

// );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String videoUrl = responseJson['link'].toString();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).